# Change sort order totals in invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, totals

How can i change the sort order in invoice PDF?

Now i have:

[image]

But i want the following:

- Subtotal
- Shipping
- Total
- TAX 6%
- TAX 21%
- Total TAX

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can customise the sort order of totals for PDFs in XML. You will need to setup a basic module (and ensure it has dependencies of `Mage_Sales` and `Mage_Tax`), then add the following code the `config.xml` of your module:

***Note:** I have left the default ordering as is below, you can customise to your needs.*

```
<global>
    <pdf>
        <subtotal>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </subtotal>
        <discount>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        </discount>
        <tax>
            <sort_order>300</sort_order>
        </tax>
        <shipping>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
        </shipping>
        <adjustment_positive>
            <sort_order>500</sort_order>
        </adjustment_positive>
        <adjustment_negative>
            <sort_order>600</sort_order>
        </adjustment_negative>
        <grand_total>
            <sort_order>700</sort_order>
        </grand_total>
    </pdf>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code found in Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php around line 547 (Magento 1.8.1) you should see:

```
$totals = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/pdf/totals')->asArray();
```

That means a  element should exist after . The config file should be:

```
<global>
    <pdf>
        <totals>
            <subtotal>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
            </subtotal>
            <discount>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            </discount>
            <tax>
                <sort_order>300</sort_order>
            </tax>
            <shipping>
                <sort_order>400</sort_order>
            </shipping>
            <adjustment_positive>
                <sort_order>500</sort_order>
            </adjustment_positive>
            <adjustment_negative>
                <sort_order>600</sort_order>
            </adjustment_negative>
            <grand_total>
                <sort_order>700</sort_order>
            </grand_total>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
</global>
```