# How to manage invoice details

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, sales

I'm using **magento 1.9.2**.

I would like to change the **invoice details** like below
"Row total
**Shipping and handling**
Discount
Total
Tax
Grand Total"

to

"Row total
Discount
Total
Tax
**Shipping and handling**
Grand Total"

I would be happy if someone gives me tips.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a module and change sort order of shipping and handling in config.xml file like below.

```
    <pdf>
        <totals>
            <shipping translate="title">
                <title>Shipping &amp; Handling</title>
                <source_field>shipping_amount</source_field>
                <font_size>7</font_size>
                <model>Inchoo_Invoice_Model_Order_Pdf_Totalpdf</model>
                <display_zero>1</display_zero>
                <sort_order>500</sort_order>
            </shipping>
        </totals>
    </pdf>
```

you need to change your module name in place of Inchoo_Invoice.
For more info you can check **Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml**

Comment: Appreciate it,where should I put those?

Comment: You need to create a new module or you can put it in existing module

Comment: And specific I want to sort invoice email and admin panel.Do those work for them?

Comment: in config.xml under global tag

Comment: Yes it will work.

Comment: Are you working on it @Shota

Comment: you meant after </pdf>?

Comment: please post your config.xml  @Shota

Comment: No Im just struggle to edit it

Comment: it's too long,mine is default
'/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml'

Comment: so you  want to change core file. Directly changes in core files is not magento standard.

Comment: Got it,so what should I do then?

Comment: in config.xml file change the sort order of shipping and handling to 500

Comment: according to my opinion in config.xml of any custom module place above code under global tag

Comment: in <pdf> to </pdf>?

Comment: yes in <pdf> to </pdf>

Comment: Thanks,it says 100-subtotal,200-discount,400-Shipping and Handling,500-Adjustment Refund,600-Adjustment Fee and 700-grand_total.

Comment: Should I change Shipping to 500?Adjustment Refund and Shipping exist on 500.Does it work?

Comment: Set these sort order according to your requirement like if subtotal has sort order value 100 then it will display very first

Comment: NOP, You need to change adjustment refund sort order too.

Comment: Sorry Im super confuse,So I jus need to put the code in <pdf>,right?

Comment: lets talk in chat, I will explain you everything

Comment: chat option is not visible on my side, I think you need to invite me on chat if chat option is visible from your side.

Comment: I cannot as well

Comment: Hello @Ramkishan I could put the code which you gave me yesterday before `grand total(700)` as  600.However it does not work at all.Do you have another solution for it?

Comment: In which config.xml file where it is placed and where you put this ?

Comment: See this :- link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62794/change-sort-order-totals-in-invoice-pdf

Comment: I just put it in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`.

Comment: I just followed that link,but I just know how to add in `Mage/Sales/etc/config.xml`.How do I edit `Mage/Tax/etc/config.xml`? @Ramkishan

Comment: You should ask new question for this because there is already more than 20 comments